# how to create an external table in sql server from parquet file in Gen2 blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, parquet, azure-data-factory, external-tables

I have created a pipeline that extract data from a datasource and store it as parquet file in a blob storage Gen2. Next after I checked the file is created by use azure storage explorer, I tried to create an external table from this parquet file in sql server management studio and it gives me the following error message

Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the external data source 'storageGen2FA - File systems', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

although I checked my permissions and I have the right one to do this operation????

SQL is Azure SQL and Data source exist

thanks in advance

Comment: Several questions: 1) Does the external data source you are referencing exist? 2) Which SQL platform is this for? [SQL Server, Azure SQL, SQLDW, etc] and 3) Why is the question tagged with azure-data-factory? Proper tagging will help you get your question in front of the right audience.

Comment: Hello Joel,
the first question  yes it does
the second question is Azure SQL
finally I tagged Azure data factory since I used it to build the pipeline that creates the parquet file.
Thank you for your comment it made the question more clear I will include those points in the question and hopefully it will help answering it